# Change Dynamic Url using htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have the following url structure:
www.mysite.com/temporary/articles.php/artid=1

I would like to change it with:
www.mysite.com/temporary/articles/article-title-here.

where article-title should be based on artid .
Anyone can tell me how can I do that?

Comment: for us to better understand the structure of your project, update your orignial post including your file structure. You can create one using this tool: http://www.filestructuregenerator.com

Comment: Artist Title has to be shown in the url based on the artist id provided in the url

Comment: RewriteRule ^temporary/([^/]+)$ articles.php?artid=$1 i have tried with this .It provides:www.mysite.com/temporary/articles/1

Comment: if you are using Codeigniter where is the `index.php` in your URL? are you already using another .htaccess?

Comment: i have removed index.php in url .I provided here only the part of url i need

Comment: issue here is to change the artist id to its corresponding artisttile in url itself.in url i will give only id of the arist it has to change dynamically to artist name pulled out from database

Comment: articles.php is a controller

Comment: dont bother about controller i need only a change in .htaccess

Comment: can u understand what i am saying

Comment: obviously I did not. I will remove my comments. I think I know what you want now, but honestly, you have to be more precise in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

No .htaccess needed. I would create another controller method and add some routes. I would use the following approach:

1. You submit the following URL: `www.mysite.com/temporary/articles.php/artid=1`
2. CI catches it and reroutes it as such:
   In your routes.php:

   ```
   $route['temporary/articles.php/artid=(:any)'] = "temporary/articles/search_by_id/$1";
   ```
3. In your Controller:

   ```
   class Articles extends CI_Controller {

       public function index($title){
            //load your model
            //from your model, query your database to get your article info by title
            //send results to your view.
       }

       public function search_by_id($id){
            //load your model
            //from your model, query your database to get your article title by id. Set it = $title
            redirect("temporary/articles/$title")
       }



   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer..but only my id is unique not my title how can solve that

Comment: well how are you currently handling that in your controller? If a user goes directly here: `www.mysite.com/temporary/articles/article-title-here.` how is your controller handling it? thats why I asked you for that code before.